# How to get system load in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to get the system load in Linux. I have tried to use the uptime command but I am just getting the average. I want to see how long it takes for the Linux system to load from shutdown or from restart. I want to see how long it takes to boot all the way up.

Comment: What precisely are you trying to measure here? I suspect you may have an incorrect idea of what the term "system load" means.

Comment: okay i think i have an idea but what i am required to do is vague

Comment: the load between the cpu or the load time which refers to the last time the system was loaded or rebooted

Comment: Are you trying to measure how long startup takes in wall time (e.g, the *uptime* when startup is complete), in CPU time (no standard term for this), or something else?

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to do

Comment: i know who -b says the last time the server was originally loaded

Comment: I want to see if there is a way to find out the time it takes to boot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try `who -b` or `last reboot | head -1`